# UML Plugin JBoss Developer Studio 4.0.0 GA

Tags: jboss, uml

What is the plug in to be added to draw Class diagram via JBoss developer studio?

My JBoss version is as below.

```
Version: 4.0.0.GA
Build id: v20110216-1930-H239-GA
Build date: 20110216-1930
```

Can anyone suggest ObjectAid version applicable for JBoss4.0

Comment: Hi Yoga!  I tried objectAid in 10.2.0.GA and couldnt get it to traverse my source folder - note I didnt select the two "license" parts of the plugin.  When I dragged the "src" folder onto the diagram it just created an element called src.  I'm looking around for something as well.  Papryus and modDisco sound interesting but Eclipse is saying they're not compatible. The search continues